# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple - How do I resolve it?

Tags: python

I am trying to compute the Confusion Matrix of a deep learning model and I keep getting this error. I have checked the data type for the 3 parameters passed and they are different data types. Could that possibly be the cause? Could someone please guide me as I am used to R and just started  using Python for my project.

```
q_aware_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
3912/3912 [==============================] - 4s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2378 - accuracy: 0.9361
Out[64]: [0.23779138922691345, 0.9361117482185364]

test_predict= q_aware_model.predict(X_test)
3912/3912 [==============================] - 4s 902us/step

cm=confusion_matrix(y_test,test_predict,Label[0,1])

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-951a7f1f1671> in <module>
----> 1 cm=confusion_matrix(y_test,test_predict,Label[0,1])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

type(Label)
Out[66] list

type(y_test)
Out[67]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

type(test_predict)
Out[68]: numpy.ndarray
```

I initially dropped Label from the df and assigned it as a list using `Label=data['Label'].tolist()`. I have now corrected it to `Label=data['Label']`. Please, how do I pass this Label in the confusion Matrix? as Label[0,1] and Label[0][1] does not seem to work.

Comment: I think `Label[0,1]` should be `Label[0][1]`.

Comment: `Label` is a list.  `[0,1]` is an illegal index for a list.

Comment: @Sean, I have tried ```Label[0][1]``` and the error I got was ```TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: Should you not just be passing in the Labels as is without indexing then? If you're using the sklearn confusion matrix then it takes a 1d list of Labels which seems to be what you have.

Comment: @Sean, thanks. I have also tried to pass the Label without indexing and got an error.

Comment: What is in your label list? It should be a set of unique classes that your output can fall into. For the confusion matrix, you can also just ignore it (set it to None) and it should give an output.

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'Label' is a list, as you can see, so you cannot access its items by passing a tuple (2 integers separated with a comma).

If you tried accessing Label[0][1] and got a TypeError ("int object is not subscriptable"), that also means Label is a list of integers.

What are you actually trying to do?

If you want to get a slice of the list, type: Label[0:1]

or simply -> Label[:1]
(If you also want the second item, just replace '1' with '2'...)

Comment: my Label is a target class consisting of Attack and Normal traffic. I used label encoder to convert the strings to 0 & 1. Perhaps the problem stems from when I dropped the class from the dataframe as -  ```Label=data['Label'].tolist()```